# React Native random.browser.js error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Today I simply cloned my project on the same computer it used to work (same commit). Everything went fine, builded etc. BUT them I receive an error saying Can't find variable: self [in random.browser.js:1:18]

the WHOLE JS FILE (yeah...)

```
var crypto = self.crypto || self.msCrypto

module.exports = function (bytes) {
  return crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(bytes))
}
```

Comment: I called npm install, umm I had a package-lock.json.
Well I just solved it by writing var crypto = self.crypto || self.msCrypto to windows.crypto || windows.msCrypto but not sure if this won't have a side effect. :(

Comment: Yeah, will try to do that! :)

Comment: Do you think modifying self to window could have a side effect later? (as react native don't have a window object :/)

Comment: Ohh this could be the problem then: crypto is not in the node modules.